# Open png images through iteration over files of different size in a given directory

Tags: python, iteration, png

I have some png-files in a given directory (C:/.../*.png). These images are of different size (e.g. 343 x 109 and 189 x 130 pixels). I would like to open this files with Python to work with this files (to show the images and to develop a neural network).

```
import os

def open_images(filename):
    with os.scandir(filename) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if entry.name.endswith(".png") and entry.is_file():
                print(entry.name, entry.path)

X_train = open_images("C:/...")
```

Obviously, this code returns only the file path. Could anyone help me to open the png-files? I think, one should also focus on the different sizes of the images. How do I handle this issue?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to open files that match a pattern it's a job for the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module. Using that module you don't need to check each files which one are good or not. You only get those that you want.

```py
import os.path
import glob

def open_images(images_directory):
    pattern_to_match = os.path.join(images_directory, "*.png")
    png_files = (x for x in glob.iglob(pattern_to_match)
                 if os.path.isfile(x))
    for current_png_filename in png_files:
        print("Opening file", current_png_filename)
        with open(current_png_filename) as current_png_file:
            # Do something with current_png_file
            pass

directory_to_search = r"C:\­…"
open_images(directory_to_search)
```

Here's what I did

- I've used [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to set where and what kind of files we are looking for
- I've used [`glob.iglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to get a iterator of names of the files that match our pattern
- And for each of the files returned from this operator, I've used [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to open each one of them.

But I didn't know what you wanted to do with them so I've used the `pass` statement to do nothing.

For example, let's say that you wanted to size (length x height) for these images. You could use the [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module to get this information. But doing so, you don't need to open the file yourself. Here's how it would look like:

```py
import os.path
import glob
import PIL.Image          # Used to do something with the images

def open_images(images_directory):
    pattern_to_match = os.path.join(images_directory, "*.png")
    png_files = (x for x in glob.iglob(pattern_to_match)
                 if os.path.isfile(x))
    for current_png_filename in png_files:
        current_image = PIL.Image.open(current_png_filename)
        print("Image", current_png_filename, "size:", current_image.size)

directory_to_search = r"C:\­…"
open_images(directory_to_search)
```

But we can simplify how we are processing the file by using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module which give us a higher level way to processing files. That would give us:

```py
import pathlib
import PIL.Image          # Used to do something with the images

def open_images(images_directory):
    png_files = (x for x in images_directory.glob('*.png')
                 if x.is_file())
    for current_png_filename in png_files:
        current_image = PIL.Image.open(current_png_filename)
        print("Image", current_png_filename, "size:", current_image.size)

directory_to_search = pathlib.Path(r"C:\­…")
open_images(directory_to_search)
```

So does that give you some indications of what you goal is?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your code works perfectly fine for opening the files. Actually, I want to get the data in a numpy array. Every entry should contain the color value of the pixel of the specific image. How do I do this? I think, we run into problems because of the different sizes of my files, aren't we?

Comment: I don't know. This is a different problem. You should ask another question for this specific problem.